# Probability density function with javascript d3 and dc

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, probability-density

I'm trying to create a probability density function of a dataset using Javascript, (d3 and dc libraries) (similar to density function of R) but I have not found how can I do it.

Can it be done?

Thanks

PD: With jqplot is this: http://services.mbi.ucla.edu/jqplot/examples/kcp_pdf.html

Comment: It's just a matter of computing the points and then plotting them. For the former, you can use anything that already exists, e.g. jqplot.

Comment: My problem was that I needed to do it with dc. I found libraries that implements KDE ([science.js](https://github.com/jasondavies/science.js)) and I used them and the results have been good. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have to be able to do with the KDE algorithm (implemented in [science.js](https://github.com/jasondavies/science.js) library)

How ever the library dc need that the data is adapted. When the data is reduced in a object with all appearances and its frequency, the object must be transformed to an array with a entry for each appearance. The groups is needed because dc need a group to paint.

My solutions has been:

```
// Creating the group
var group = dimension.group().reduceSum();
......
// Process the object. 
groups = group.all()
var newValues = []
for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < groups[i].value;j++){
        if (groups[i].key == "null" ||
            groups[i].key == null ||
            (groups[i].key - start < 0) ||
            (groups[i].key - end > 0)) {
        } else {
            newValues.push(parseFloat(groups[i].key))
        }
    }
}
.....
// Creating the new data that represent a density function. 
var kde = science.stats.kde().sample(newValues);
// I have replaced the bandwidth method (Multivariate Density Estimation)
// because this method works better than previous (Density Estimation) 
// min and max are calculated previously 
kde.bandwidth(science.stats.bandwidth.nrd0);
var frequency = Math.abs(parseFloat(max) - parseFloat(min)) / 512
var newData = kde(d3.range(min,max,frequency));

.....
// The array that is inside of the group is a reference (obviously but it is important)
// Deleting the contains of the array
groups.splice(0,groups.length) 
// add the new data
for (var key in newData) {
    groups.push({key:newData[key][0],value:newData[key][2]
})
```